# Angular 2 : How to watch service variables?

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular, observable, angular-services

See the below code,

```
    @Component({
         template: `<div *ngIf="loggedIn">show this when logged in</div>
                    <div> other content </div>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
         providers: [UserService]
    })
    class App{
         private loggedIn:boolean;
    }
    @Injectable()
    class UserService{
         loggedIn:boolean = false;
         getIsLoggedIn(){return this.loggedIn;}
         setLoggedIn(){this.loggedIn = true;}
    }
    @Component({
         template: '<div (click)="login()"></div>'
    })
    class LoginComponent{
         login(){userService.setLoggedIn();}
    }
    bootstrap(App);
```

Consider that by default router config takes to login component. I have omitted some dependency injection code too (so that is not an error). Now I want that the div in App component show be visible only when UserService's `loggedIn` variable becomes true.

I have seen directive variable watching but not sure how to do that across components and with service.

Comment: If you don't think this is a duplicate add a comment and we get it reopened.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Didn't find because of keywords.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)